# URDF limits differential robot

Tags: ros, urdf, limits

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm creating a differential robot and for the wheels I'm using revolute joints. I don't understand the  property I have to add. More specifically the lower and upper fields, the effort and velocity are somewhat understandable. Should I just go yolo and add this to my robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203390/urdf-limits-differential-robot/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

revolute joints are rotating joints with limits. You'll want to use a continuous joint, which is a rotating joint without limits (i.e. allowing continuous rotation). See also [URDF joint wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2